Apexchart the file isn't available on site error

        let chart;

        document.addEventListener('dataLoaded', (data) => {
            options.series[0].data = data.detail[0][1];
            chart = new ApexCharts(document.getElementById("column-chart"), options);
            chart.render();

            document.getElementById('svg').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                chart.dataURI().then((uri) => {
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.download = "chart.svg";
                    link.href = uri.svg;
                    link.click();
                });
            });

            document.getElementById('png').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                chart.dataURI().then((uri) => {
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.download = "chart.png";
                    link.href = uri.png;
                    link.click();
                });
            });

            document.getElementById('csv').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                chart.dataURI({
                    type: 'csv',
                    filename: 'chart.csv'
                }).then((csv) => {
                    var blob = new Blob([csv], {
                        type: 'text/csv'
                    });
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.download = "chart.csv";
                    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    link.click();
                });
            });
        });

Does anyone know the error code above, why when downloading Apexchart the file isn't available on site error occurs?
Does anyone know the error code above, why when downloading Apexchart the file isn't available on site error occurs?
